# Map a mocha test to jira id

Tags: javascript, automation, mocha.js, jira, requirements

I have a bunch of mocha tests, is there a way to map every test to a jira ticket? The intention behind it is, when I have the test report, I click on any test, and it takes me back to the actual jira page. (Tests to Requirements mapping)

NOTE: We do not have a test management tool yet. So will be using JIRA ticket as the source of truth.

Any pointers around this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have the below implementation for cypress tests:

1. I include the JIRA issue number in the test title.
2. There are cypress events, at the end of every test, I grab the title and strip off the JIRA id and pass it to the mochawesome context.
   cypress/support/index.js

```
Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test, runnable) => {
  const { parent } = runnable;

  const jiraId = test.title;
  jiraId.replace(/\w+-\w+/, match => {
    const name = match;
    addContext(
      { test },
      {
        title: 'JIRA',
        value: `https://jira.sendgrid.net/browse/${name}`,
      }
    );
  });
});
```

3. Then in the test reports it looks like this.

[image]

4. Click on the jira link and you can navigate to your actual jira ticket.